# Using an external touchscreen on Ubuntu 22.04 Wayland problem

Tags: 22.04, wayland, touchscreen, external-monitor, libinput

I have an external AOC 16T2 touchscreen, which is recognized as an touchscreen.

In X11 this works fine in *extended desktop/join displays* after mapping the touch input to the external screen.

```
 xinput map-to-output <xinput-id> <xrandr-id>
```

BTW I'm not sure why this is not the default, because having to touch the external monitor to click on a link on the first monitor does not make any sense IMHO.

In Wayland this does not work. `xinput` (wrapper) is not recognizing the monitor anymore, so there is no `<xinput-id>`

The touchscreen is still working, but a click on the secondary screen is recorded as a click on the first screen, which is wrong.

`libinput` is listing the device:

```
Device:           Melfas LGDisplay Incell Touch
Kernel:           /dev/input/event13
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             341x195mm
Capabilities:     touch 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      identity matrix
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a
```

How can I fix the input mapping problem in the default Ubuntu 22.04 Wayland?